# how can i put all the emojis that exist in my dataset into a new file?

Tags: python, emoji

how can i put all the emojis that exist in my dataset into a new file ?

```
import emoji
import re

test_list=['  thankyou']
```

### Create the function to extract the emojis

```
def extract_emojis(a_list):
emojis_list = map(lambda x: ''.join(x.split()), 
emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI.keys())
r = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(p) for p in emojis_list))
aux=[' '.join(r.findall(s)) for s in a_list]
return(aux)
```

### Execute the function

```
extract_emojis(test_list)
```

Comment: What's the error in your code?

Comment: your code is running correctly dude.

Comment: not an error but how can i put the emojis into a file without repetition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to iterate over the list returned by `extract_emojis(test_list)`, and write each item in the list to a file:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for emoji in extract_emojis(test_list):
        myfile.write(emoji)
```

Edit: if you don't want to add any duplicate emojis into the file, you first need to read the contents of the file, and then check if each emoji already exists before adding it:

```
with open("somefile.txt","r", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    filecontent = myfile.read()

with open('somefile.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for comment in extract_emojis(test_list):
      for emoji in comment:
        if emoji != ' ' and emoji not in filecontent:
          myfile.write(emoji)
```

Comment: that will give me a list with repetitions

Comment: @zakariazakaria can you explain what you mean? Do you mean that you want to overwrite the file every time the code is run instead of adding to it?

Comment: i want the same thing as you did but if the emoji already exist in the file, no need to add it again for example in the first comment i have :) and in the second one i have :p and the third another :) the result will be ":) and :p "

Comment: yes this what i want tank you just another question if i want to have the list line by line

Comment: @zakariazakaria then use `myfile.write(emoji+'\n')` instead of `myfile.write(emoji)` (`\n` is a newline character)